# Вывод строки посимвольно с задержкой для телеграм-бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот

Можно ли сделать эффект вывода строки посимвольно с задержкой для телеграм-бота? вот пример этой функции

```
import time

def print_with_delay(text, delay):
    for char in text:
        print(char, end='', flush=True)  # Печать символа без перевода строки
        time.sleep(delay)  # Задержка между символами

# Пример использования
text_to_display = "Привет, мир!"
delay_time = 0.1  # Задержка в секундах

print_with_delay(text_to_display, delay_time)
```

Можно ли использовать это для приветствия или там какое - то особенное уведомление от бота ?

Comment: Вы вполне можете изменять уже отправленное сообщение. Следовательно алгоритм прост: отправляем одну букву, изменяем сообщение и "сохраняем" его с двумя буквами и т.д.. Но вопрос тут в другом, а зачем?)

Comment: Нуу для уникальности для контраста для красоты я хочу если смогу придумать еще сделать такой эффект как типо каждая буква еще и крутилась несколько раз, еще хочу в некоторых моментах хочу покрасить символа )

Comment: или настроить opacity с циклом, ну кароче пахать надо :-D

Comment: Тогда смотрите в сторону отправленнего сообщения, запоминайте его id, вызывайте его на редактирование и будет то что вы хотите.

Comment: @Amgarak Тоесть вы имейте ввиду типо можно все это сделать "после" отправки сообщения ?

Comment: Отправили 1 символ "П", затем отредактировали это же сообщение через его id и "сохранили" его уже с 2 символами "Пр" и так далее...

Comment: аа балиин! понял реально вроде понял... поставлю галочку когда сделаю :-)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150570/discussion-between-chc-and-amgarak).

Comment: @Amgarak, получилось но с 2 проблемами... Вы оказывается не зря спросили "зачем"! :-) 
1) Не хочет отправлять "пробел"
2) Задержка реально само по себе появляется, 1 редактирование это 1 запрос... я об этом не подумал

Comment: @Amgarak спасибо за подсказку.

Comment: Был рад помочь;))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно. В телеграм-ботах нету flush и других плюшек, которые есть в стандартном print, поэтому я переписал код и подключил библиотеку aiogram для использования ботов. Вот код:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from asyncio import sleep

bot = Bot(token='токен')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands='start') #ответ на команду /start
async def start(message: types.Message):
    text = 'Привет, мир!'
    delay = 0.1
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    message_info = await message.answer(text[0])
    for i in range(2, len(text) + 2):
        new_message = text[0:i]
        if new_message[len(new_message) - 1] != ' ': #aiogram не видит пробелов и ругается когда сообщение не изменяется, поэтому не меняем сообщение если символ = пробел
            await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=chat_id, message_id=int(message_info.message_id), text=new_message)
        await sleep(delay) #так как aiogram ассинхронный, здесь другая функция задержки

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Comment: я никак не могу определится между telebot и aiogram ) я еще не начал пока, гуглю пока "что лучше telebot или iogram... что посоветуете ?

Comment: Лично я использую aiogram, и мне он удобнее. Однако кому как. Они отличаются асинхронностью и некоторыми командами, поэтому я советую попробовать оба и выбрать, который более удобный.

Comment: понял вас спасибо!